# Variable reuse in YAML, variable within variable

Tags: yaml

I'm looking for a way to reuse variables defined in my list on YAML, I have a YAML list with the following sample entries :

```
workstreams:
  - name: tigers
    service_workstream: tigers-svc
    virtual_user:
      - {name: inbound-tigers, pass: '123', access: inbound, env: app1}
      - {name: outbound-tigers, pass: '123', access: outbound, env: app1}
    email: tigers@my-fqdn.com
    mount_dir: /mnt/tigers
    app_config_dir: /opt/tigers
```

Using the example from above I want to reuse a defined value, like *tigers*. The ideal solution would be something like this :

```
workstreams:
  - name: tigers
    service_workstream: "{{ vars['name'] }}-svc"
    virtual_user:
      - {name: "inbound-{{ vars['name'] }}", pass: '123', access: inbound, env: app1}
      - {name: "outbound-{{ vars['name'] }}", pass: '123', access: outbound, env: app1}
    email: "{{ vars['name'] }}@my-fqdn.com"
    mount_dir: "/mnt/{{ vars['name'] }}"
    app_config_dir: "/opt/{{ vars['name'] }}"
```

Any points as to how I can do this in YAML ?

Comment: I always wonder how in such a situation `vars` would be linked with a mapping that is a list element, where the list is a value in a (toplevel) mapping. If that would be `workstreams[0]['name']` or even `workstream.0.name` I could imagine that it can be done (although not in the YAML spec), but using `vars`, no way.

Comment: @Anthon: I thought about doing something like that in upcoming YAML 1.3, but other things are currently more important for us. My idea would be to couple it to aliases, so you'd need an anchor on the root level like `&root` and could then do `*root.workstreams.1.name` (I fancy 1-based indexing).

Answer (score 18):

You can do:

```
workstreams:
  - name: &name tigers          # the scalar "tigers" with an anchor &name
    service_workstream: *name   # alias, references the anchored scalar above
```

However, you can *not* do string concatenation or anything like it in YAML 1.2. It cannot do any transformations on the input data. An alias is really a reference to the node that holds the corresponding anchor, it is not a variable.

Quite some YAML-using software provides non-YAML solutions to that problem, for example, preprocessing the YAML file with Jinja or whatnot. Depending on context, that may or may not be a viable solution for you.